# Retrieving a specific value in an array from JSP to Servlet

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, servlets, jstl

This code creates a table out of an array of strings stored inside a session. 
I then have a submit button on the end of each row which when clicked should store the Stock number of reach row (placed in the 0th column of each row) and send it to the servlet. The table is displaying properly, however I cannot retrieve the Stock# column for each individual row.
Where did I go wrong?

```
 <table>  
  <tr>  

      <th>Stock#</th>  <th>Name</th>  <th>Price</th>  <th>Description</th>  

  </tr>  
  <c:forEach items="${BooksTable}" begin="0" var="row">  
    <tr>  
      <c:forEach items="${row}" var="cell"> 

        <td>${cell} <BR>  <BR>  </td>  
      </c:forEach>  
      <c:set value="${$row.count}" scope="session" var="itemID" />
       <td><FORM ACTION="CartAccess">

         <INPUT TYPE ="HIDDEN" NAME="item" VALUE="${BooksTable[1][0]}">

        <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="check" VALUE="Add"> </FORM></td>   
    </tr>  
  </c:forEach>  
</table>
```

Comment: What is `BooksTable`? Have you debugged to determine that the value   truly exists for Stock #? Also, what are you trying to do with `<c:set value="${$row.count}" scope="session" var="itemID" />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a test to check If the `index == 0` , if it is then `c:set` a variable `stockValue` and then use it to create Hidden field.

```
   <c:forEach items="${BooksTable}" begin="0" var="row">  
    <tr>  
      <c:forEach items="${row}" var="cell" varStatus="rowIndex"> 

        <c:if test="${rowIndex.index == 0}" >
           <c:set var="stockValue" value="${cell}" scope="page" />
       </c:if>

        <td>${cell} <BR>  <BR>  </td>  
      </c:forEach>  

      <c:set value="${$row.count}" scope="session" var="itemID" />
       <td><FORM ACTION="CartAccess">
         <INPUT TYPE ="HIDDEN" NAME="item" VALUE="${stockValue}">
        <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="check" VALUE="Add"> </FORM></td>   
    </tr>  
  </c:forEach>
```